# How to programmatically  add ImageView in LinearLayout without extra spaces?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I am trying to add ImageView programatically inside a LinearLayout, which has vertical orientation. My layout file is describe as the xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingTop="5dip"
   android:id="@+id/mainView"">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/tvTituloInformacao"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:shadowColor="@color/black_translucent"
    android:shadowDx="2.0"
    android:shadowDy="2.0"
    android:shadowRadius="3.0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" /> 

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/resourceContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"          
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTituloInformacao"
    android:background="@color/black_translucent2" /> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And my java source code that adds the ImageViews to the LinearLayout is as follow:

```
for(Resource r : mUser.getPictures()) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    img.setTag(r.getThumb60());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(r.getThumb60(), this, img);
    ((LinearLayout) tempFotosView.findViewById(R.id.resourceContainer)).addView(img);
}
```

What happens is that before and after each ImageView I am getting some extra spaces that should not be there, so the height of the images container increases a lot. One test that I did and got the expected result was not to use the imageLoader and instead I set the ImageResource programatically to a static image file. This way I didn't get any extra space.

The weird result is illustrated in the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to not add this extra space?

Comment: You should cache the LinearLayout outside of the For Loop to increase the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think images you are loading in image views may have some extra spacing on top and bottom, and other assumption you are loading images in imageview, with different resolution than your screen-size, and setting scaleType of ImageView to centerInside, if it is the case please try using following by fixing height of the image view as well, and set scaleType to fixXY.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the image is wider than the screen size after the ImageView has been built. Android shrinks the image's dimensions accordingly to aspect ratio, but doesn't remove the allocated space around it earlier.

For a cleaner fix, try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776016/1402526) after your imageLoader.

Answer (score -2):

```
  ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.resource)).add(img);
```

Comment: There is no such method like `add` ; before posting some answer you should know what you say.