# Basic issue with layout of imageView in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that contain one imageView
I want this imageView matching the parent width, full width of the screen and then keep ratio aspect, so wrapping the height.

My options where :
 - layout_widht : match_parent
 - layout_height : wrap_content
 - scaletype : centerCrop

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cellarWineImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/etiquette_unknown" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the result

[image]

If I just put a fixe height 348dp the result is here

[image]

After fighting, I suspect that the wrap content, consider the original height of the image, doesn't matter if the size change due to match parent of the width. Please help for such basic topic. And I hope we can handle this without making any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Akshat Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20427215/2733216) great answer, we can use simple stuff by extending ImageView into a  a new component : AspectRatioImageView, and then reusing it directly in the layout.

```
package com.yourpackage.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if (getDrawable() == null)
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        else {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = width * getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight() / getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use it in the XML:

```
<com.yourpackage.widgets.AspectRatioImageView android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/yourdrawable" android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

This works great on my project, by just changing curent ImageView, by this new packageName. Then everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I've set android:src in my layout yet getDrawable() is returning null. When I check for null it's crashing anyway: java.lang.IllegalStateException: onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

Comment: @Makalele at the beginning, it seems the drawable is null, before the content is set, or inflated, probably the normal life cycle. So you can just do the job as soon as the drawable is present. That work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting on `LinearLayout, ImageView and ScrollView` your `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to see if works.

Comment: He should probably remove the 'center crop' in his ImageView also

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that, but I guess you are right !

Comment: I used match_parent (which is recommend, I hope is the same), that look better, but it is a fake, the ratio aspect is not preserved. To better checked, I put 2 images view, one after the other, and one is hidden by the other.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cellarWineImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Haresh, but the image is not wrapping to its maximum size (the screen width). The view wrap width well, but the image inside is small. The height has not really sense (2/5 of the screen height)

Answer (score 0):

change the layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:minHeight="348dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cellarWineImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:minHeight="348dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u try that, is it fine

Comment: Thanks but this picture was an example, si I can have many different size to display during runtime