# How to aspect fill programmatically? [Android]

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to `Aspect Fill` my image. The size of my image is 1242x168. What I want is that if my screen is small my image will be cut and left align but it seems that it keeps on being `aspect fit`.

Here is my code

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int device_width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float dpWidth  = displaymetrics.widthPixels / density;

if(dpWidth >= 768) {
                int aspectRatio = (int) (0.135 * device_width);
                gifImageView.getLayoutParams().height = aspectRatio;
                gifImageView.getLayoutParams().width = device_width;
            }
```

Here is my xml

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/displayImage"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

I tried using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but it is crop in center I wanted to cut the right side that is why I wanted to be left align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing this

```
//Get width of device
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpWidth  = displaymetrics.widthPixels / density;

   if(dpWidth > 768 ) { 
      int aspectRatio = (int) (0.135 * device_width);
      gifImageView.getLayoutParams().height = aspectRatio;
      gifImageView.getLayoutParams().width = device_width;
      gifImageView.setIsScale(false);
    }else{
        int aspectRatio = (int) (0.219 * device_width);
        gifImageView.getLayoutParams().height = aspectRatio;
        gifImageView.getLayoutParams().width = device_width;
     gifImageView.setScaleType(ProportionalImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        gifImageView.setIsScale(true);
    }
```

And create a cuztomized class that extends to `ImageView` / `GifImageView`

```
 public class ProportionalImageView extends GifImageView {

Boolean isScale = false;

public ProportionalImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if(isScale) {
        setup();
    }
}

public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    if(isScale) {
        setup();
    }
}

public ProportionalImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if(isScale) {
        setup();
    }
}

private void setup() {
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
}

@Override
protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    if(isScale) {
        computeMatrix();
    }

    return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if(isScale) {
        computeMatrix();
    }
}

private void computeMatrix() {
    Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
    float scaleFactor, scaleFactorWidth, scaleFactorHeight;
    scaleFactorWidth = (float) getWidth() / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    scaleFactorHeight = (float) getHeight() / (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    if (scaleFactorHeight > scaleFactorWidth) {
        scaleFactor = scaleFactorHeight;
    } else {
        scaleFactor = scaleFactorWidth;
    }

    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

public void setIsScale(Boolean isScale){
    this.isScale = isScale;
}

public Boolean getIsScale() {
    return isScale;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Scaling your image based on screen width:

```
public static float getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
    Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    float pxWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    return pxWidth;
}

float screenWidth=getScreenWidth(act)
float newHeight = screenWidth;
if (bitmap.getWidth() != 0 && bitmap.getHeight() != 0) {
 newHeight = (screenWidth * bitmap.getHeight()) / bitmap.getWidth();
}

Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) screenWidth, (int) newHeight, true);

android:adjustViewBounds=true.
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Links: [Resizing ImageView to fit to aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400113/resizing-imageview-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio), 
https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179

Comment: it is still `aspect fit` it fits the image to the container :( not cutting the image.

Comment: but using `centerCrop` will crop it to center. Is there a way to left align it?